# Prepared statement is not getting executed with TypeScript and mssql NodeJS package

Tags: sql-server, node.js, typescript

I'm using TypeScript and mssql (v4) NodeJS package to connect my application to a SQL Server database.
I'm facing that it seems that the code defined for sql.ConnectionPool is not being called and I was not able to figure out the reason.
Basically I want to perform an INSERT operation using a prepared statement.
Here's my code of CRUD.ts file:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'MyDB',
    user: 'MyUser',
    password: '*******',
    port: '1433'
};

export async function newItem(someValue1: string, someValue2: string) {
    try {
        const db = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, err => {
            console.info("Checking for errors...");
            if (err) {
                console.error("Connection failed: " + err);
            } else {
                console.info("Connected")
                const insertStatement = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyData]([SomeValue1],[SomeValue2])VALUES(@SomeValue1, @SomeValue2)';
                const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(db);
                ps.input('SomeValue1', sql.String)
                ps.input('SomeValue2', sql.String)
                ps.prepare(insertStatement, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    } else {
                        ps.execute({
                            SomeValue1: someValue1,
                            SomeValue2: someValue2
                        }, (err, result) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                            } else {
                                ps.unprepare(err => {
                                    if (err) {
                                        console.error(err);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });     
    }catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }

}
```

I tried following several examples on [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) documentation with no success.

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using an `async` function so you really should rewrite your code to use `await` instead of callbacks. e.g. `result = await ps.prepare(insertStatement)` and then you can avoid many levels of nested callbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used this particular library, but I think rewriting your code to use `async/await` will help a lot, especially as you have already marked the function itself as async. If you do that then your call to `await newItem(...)` will wait for all of the processing to complete instead of as now returning immediately before any of the callbacks have triggered.

Here's what I think your code could look like (but untested so may have some errors):

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'MyDB',
    user: 'MyUser',
    password: '*******',
    port: '1433'
};

export async function newItem(someValue1: string, someValue2: string) {
    let db;
    try {
      db = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.error("Connection failed: " + err);
      throw(err);
    }
    try {     
      console.info("Connected")
      const insertStatement = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyData]([SomeValue1],[SomeValue2])VALUES(@SomeValue1, @SomeValue2)';
      const ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(db);
      ps.input('SomeValue1', sql.String)
      ps.input('SomeValue2', sql.String)
      await ps.prepare(insertStatement);
      await ps.execute({
            SomeValue1: someValue1,
            SomeValue2: someValue2
        });
      await ps.unprepare();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        throw(e);
    }
}
```

Note that I added a call to `.connect()` on the pool as the documentation seems to imply that is required. When you use `await` any errors should come back as `Promise` rejections which the `await` turns into exceptions. That means instead of checking each call for an error code you just need a single `try...catch` (actually two of them here to keep the different message you use for a connection error).

I also re-threw the errors to indicate to the caller that the code failed. If you just want to errors to bubble up to the caller then you could also remove the error handling entirely: as errors turn into Promise rejections or exceptions they will propagate upwards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Duncan! I implemented it as you suggested and then I was facing another issue. But I was able to solve it.
I was having another async function that was calling the already mentioned one:

return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
 DBOperations.newItem(someValue1, someValue2);
})

I just added the async and await keyword, as shown below:

return await new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
 await DBOperations.newItem(someValue1, someValue2);
})

Comment: @danielcode7 an async function already returns a `Promise` so remove the `new Promise` and just return the call directly: `return DBOperations.newItem(someValue1, someValue2);` you don't even have to await the result as you're just passing the Promise back.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that point, but I'm using `new Promise` because the calling function (another async function) will return another different Promise with the `resolve()` method.